# intellij accessing invalid virtual file

Tags: intellij-idea

Please help me I am stuck due to below weird behavior of Intellij 2021.2.4(Ultimate Edition)
I am getting error after opening project in Intellij as below :

**"Accessing invalid virtual file: file://; original:12323; found:12333; File.exists()=true.**

I restarted my machine on weekend and then opened the Intellij Idea today morning .
I have tried below solutions but in vain
1.Invalid Caches
2.Remove idea64.exe.vmoptions

Thanks in advance .

Comment: What custom plugins do you use? Check the idea.log file (Help | Show Log in ... action) after IDE restart and reproducing. Any errors there?

Comment: @Andrey Thanks for you adviceI am using Maven plugin only . Where can I find log file , can you please guide

Comment: You can find it using Help | **Show Log in ...*** action.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue just now. For me, I was running our app via JavaScript Debug task and the app would immediately fail; I'd get the error message in a "red balloon" above my Debug tool window tab.

Following the advice of [@Andrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2000323/andrey) I checked the logs. Sure enough, there was a hint:

```
com.intellij.openapi.vfs.InvalidVirtualFileAccessException: Accessing invalid virtual file: file:///Users/randy/projects/..../.../notifications; original:804838; found:805846; File.exists()=true
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.impl.VirtualDirectoryImpl.handleInvalidDirectory(VirtualDirectoryImpl.java:190)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.impl.VirtualDirectoryImpl.doFindChild(VirtualDirectoryImpl.java:111)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.impl.VirtualDirectoryImpl.findChild(VirtualDirectoryImpl.java:77)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.impl.VirtualDirectoryImpl.findChild(VirtualDirectoryImpl.java:500)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.impl.VirtualDirectoryImpl.findChild(VirtualDirectoryImpl.java:44)
    at com.intellij.javascript.debugger.JavaScriptDebugProcess.isMeteorClientScript(JavaScriptDebugProcess.kt:587)
    at com.intellij.javascript.debugger.JavaScriptDebugProcess.getLocationsForBreakpoint(JavaScriptDebugProcess.kt:538)
    at com.intellij.javascript.debugger.JSLineBreakpointManagerBase.setBreakpoint(JSLineBreakpointManagerBase.kt:36)
    at com.intellij.javascript.debugger.breakpoints.JSLineBreakpointHandler.registerBreakpoint(JSLineBreakpointHandler.kt:17)
    at com.intellij.javascript.debugger.breakpoints.JSLineBreakpointHandler.registerBreakpoint(JSLineBreakpointHandler.kt:12)
```

IntelliJ was trying to register breakpoints when it crashed. From there, I simply opened the Breakpoints dialog and trashed everything since they were all recent and moot anyway.

After that, I just closed the debug browser window that was left from my last failed attempt, then reran the Debug config. Everything worked as expected.

Comment: I guess it works for all IntelliJ-based products.  I could fix it with WebStorm too. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I forcefully removed a module and then got this kind of error.
In my case, the error disappeared just by invalidating and restarting the IDE, note that you should check to `Clear file system cache and local history`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me, just go to [image]
and removing all breakpoints fixed the problem